# It is possible to detect blurry text?

Tags: images

Is it possible to reveal the concealed text?

[image]

Comment: No. You are out of luck on this one

Comment: The only reason I can think of to need this is to try and detect something the original creator would rather you **not** see. So, essentially, only for nefarious reasons.

Comment: No it is not a crime

Comment: Then *why* would you need to "unblur" text in an image so it's readable if you don't have the original?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing at all to do with design.

Answer (score 3):

Without context, it's tough to make a diagnosis.

Basically, if that's all your being provided with, there is no way to reveal that text. There is no software that could perform the action if this is a flat graphic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple one ended solution to be able to do this but a similar question was asked like this on StackOverflow called [Is there a way to detect if an image is blurry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry)

In regards to your image, you are out of luck and you will have to go back to the source.  If this is for a print and the client may not have the originals you could always request to contact the printer to see if they may have a PDF to send to you.